# SetPageLoad Timeout not working for Selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In my `webdriver` test, I have the below. Despite the `SetPageLoadTimeout`, the script is still executing the next line before allowing the page to load.

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("MySurvey")).Click();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

Answer (score 2):

`SetPageLoadTimeout` is saying how long you want to wait for the page to load before the test fails.

What you're after is waiting for an element to appear:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```